# Laravel: Updating multiple files in array

Tags: arrays, laravel, file, upload

I was able to store and save multiple files in the array into the database, as well as updating the form data. However, the problem now is it returns this error when I *update the form without updating the `file`*.

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Does anyone know what should I do for my `update` function or `value` in my blade file so that it won't delete the `file` elements?

--------------------------------------------- **UPDATED** ---------------------------------------------

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{        
    $data = $request->all();
    $data = $this->saveEmptyData($data);

    $c = Document::find($id);
    $fileData = [];

    if(count($request->file)>0)
    {
        foreach($request->file as $file)
        {    
            $path = public_path('storage/documents');
            $fileName = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($path, $fileName);

            if ($c->file)
            {
                File::delete($path.'/'.json_decode($c->file)[0]);
            }
            $fileData[] = $fileName;
        }
        $doc = json_encode($fileData);
        $c->file = $doc;
        
        $c->name = $request->name;
        $c->price = $request->price;
        $c->publish = $request->publish;
    } 
    //else {
    //    redirect()->back()->with('errors', 'File is required!');
    //}
    $c->save();

    return redirect()->route('product.index')->with('success', 'Document updated successfully');
}
```

**Blade**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('document.update', $doc) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        ....
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Document</label>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <label for="upload_file">Upload</label>
                <input id="upload_file" type="file" name="file[]" value="{{ isset($doc) ? $doc['file'] : '' }}" multiple>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(count($request->file)>0)
 {
   foreach($request->file as $file)
   { 
      $path = public_path('documents/');
      $fileName = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
      $file->move($path, $fileName);

      if ($c->file)
      {
         File::delete($path.'/'.json_decode($c->file)[0]);
      }

      $fileData[] = $fileName;
   }
   $doc= json_encode($fileData); //replace $doc['file'] with $doc
   $c->file=$doc;
 }

$c->save();
//not required to declare $fileData ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the `file` is finally updated, but it returns `count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable` when I update the form without updating the `file`.

Answer (score 0):

`enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag

```
if(count($request->file)>0)
{
    foreach($request->file as $file)
    { 
        $path = public_path('documents/');
        $fileName = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move($path, $fileName);

        if ($c->file)
        {
            File::delete($path.'/'.json_decode($c->file)[0]);
        }

        $fileData[] = $fileName;
    }
    $doc['file'] = json_encode($fileData);
}
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: It returns `[{},{}]` for the column `file` in my database